# I need help with essay question: "'No act is intrinsically criminal'. Discuss"

Tags: reference-request, psychology

I've been given the writing prompt "'No act is intrinsically criminal'. Discuss" How should I go about thinking about the writing prompt? What are some philosophical issues I should think about in doing my writing?

Comment: I'd look up the definitions of "intrinsic" and "criminal", and then I'd decide to either make an argument that indeed no act is intrinsically criminal, or find an act that is intrinsically criminal. I'd have a look at two different definitions of "crime", where one says "against the laws" and the other includes "a foolish, senseless or shameful act".

Comment: If I were a betting man, I'd wager the assignment you've been given isn't to write an essay titled "*No Act is Instrinsically Criminal: Discuss*" but instead to write an essay with the title "*No act is intrinsically criminal*" and your essay should *discuss* that topic.

Comment: @gnasher729, in addition to *"foolish, senseless or shameful"*, i would include "grievously harmful" and "unfair" in the service of one's own self-interest.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Quite true. The major difference between the definitions is that one defines things as criminal _if there is a law against them_ which means the act would not be criminal if the laws were different, while the other definition defines things as criminal based on the thing itself.

Comment: there are plenty of examples in history where decidedly criminal acts were committed where there was either no law at all prevailing or that the law failed to identify those acts as illegal.

Answer (score 2):

You are being asked to decide what you think about whether some actions are always criminal by nature or not, and then to defend your choice.

For instance, is killing another human being always a criminal act?  Society says "no", not in the case of a soldier at war, or in the case of a executioner hired by the government.  What about euthanasia (doctor-assisted suicide for the terminally ill)?  What about shootings by police?  America, right now, is in the middle of a big debate over whether police officers have too much protection from being charged as criminals for wrongful killings.

That's the kind of question you need to explore in your essay.  It will also be important that you choose one point of view ("yes, some acts are always criminal") or the other ("no, there are no acts that are always criminal") and that you do your best to convince the reader that you have considered the opposite point of view and still have good reasons to think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple things you can look at. Obviously, this is from a philosophical, and not legal perspective.

1. [A recent episode](http://www.historyofphilosophy.net/abelard-ethics) of *The History of Philosophy* podcast addressed a similar issue. As the episode discusses, Peter Abelard argued that it is the intention that matters more in judging whether an action is good or bad, rather than the act itself.
2. The position will obviously matter whether you argue that the criminal code and the notion of Justice/Virtue should be in alignment (or, to put another way, what is the source of the criminal code: some objective idea of right and wrong, or whatever is willed by the ruler/ruling institution/people). Plato seems to say in the Republic that the ideal city will have just laws, but someone like Machiavelli would say that a ruler [may need to do immoral things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prince#Conquests_by_.E2.80.9Ccriminal_virtue.E2.80.9D_.28Chapter_8.29), and thus there is not necessarily a connection.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to examine the arguments of a political theorist interested in the notions of crime, justice and the individual man (or woman); and that in relation to a historical event.

Take for example the book *Eichmann in Jerusalem: A report into the banality of evil* by the political theorist Hannah Arendt; and notice that the sub-title is asking the same question that you are being asked and so should prove helpful in understanding the dimensions of this question; it's worth quoting from this entry:

> Her thesis is that Eichmann was not a fanatic or a sociopath but an average man; who relied on cliche rather than thinking for himself and was motivated by professional promotion rather than ideology.
>
> Banality is not in this sense, not that his actions were ordinary, and not that there are potential Eichmans in all of us; but that he was motivated by a kind of stupidity that was wholly unexceptional.

Another tack would be to take a fictionalised representation of what justice may or may not mean; for example William Goldings *Lord of the Flies* or Harper Lees *To Kill a Mocking Bird* and ask this question to the events described there.